# Codeigniter -> Select Menu Form Validation

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have come to writing my controller code after doing the view:

A few questions regarding the Select Menus:

- How do I validate the select menu - I do not want them to be able to select “Please Select”
- Can I still use `$this->form_validation->set_rules('','','required');`
- How do I send the correct answer into the controller?

  ```
      <label for="hostingRequired">Hosting Required:</label>
          <select name="hostingRequired">
              <option value="pleaseSelect"> Please Select</option>
                  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                  <option value="no">No</option>
              </select>
      <label for="domainRequired">Domain Registration: </label>
                  <select name="domainRequired">
                      <option value="pleaseSelect">Please Select</option>
                      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                      <option value="no">No</option>
                  </select>
      <div id="domainToBeReged">
                  <label for="domainToBeReged">Domain:</label><input name="domainToBeReged" type="text" placeholder="http://www." />
                  <label for="domainToBeReged0">Domain:</label><input name="domainToBeReged0" type="text" placeholder="http://www." />
      </div>
  ```

Comment: I think just removing the value of the "Please Select" option would do the trick here. I don't have my CI installation here, so I can't really test it, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following

then use the following validation rule

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('','','required|callback_is_default');

function is_default($array)
{
  foreach($array as $element)
  {
    if($element == 'pleaseSelect')
    { 
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
 return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: But then when the validation kicks in would it not say that error 0 is not required?  instead of 0 could I use pleaseSelect?

Comment: Oh ok yeah you could do that.

Comment: In the is_default helper, you could also set a message. In the example linked, they set an error message in the callback function.

[CodeIgniter reference on Callbacks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt find validation rule that you want, extend Validation library and write your own rule. [Look example](http://www.scottnelle.com/41/extending-codeigniters-validation-library/) how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your validation rules add:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('hostingRequired','Hosting Required','required|callback__check_select_yes_or_no');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('domainRequired','Domain registration','required|callback__check_select_yes_or_no');
```

Also, add this additional method to your controller as a validation rule callback:

```
function _check_select_yes_or_no($str)
{
    if ($str != 'yes' && $str != 'no')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_select_yes_or_no', 'Please select yes or no for the %s field');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

This will work for 'Yes' or 'No' options - if you would like to add more adjust the callback, or invert the check to fail if the user selects 'Please select'.

Alternatively, a better way to do this may be to use radio buttons for 'Yes' and 'No' and not have one 'checked' when the form loads.

```
<fieldset><legend> Hosting required:</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="hostingRequired" value="yes">Yes</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="hostingRequired" value="no">No</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doin this is as follows:

- first you set the value of the default option to empty
- second you use a simple validation rule

So here goes the code

```
<label for="hostingRequired">Hosting Required:</label>
    <select name="hostingRequired">
        <option value=""> Please Select</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
<label for="domainRequired">Domain Registration: </label>
            <select name="domainRequired">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
<div id="domainToBeReged">
            <label for="domainToBeReged">Domain:</label><input name="domainToBeReged" type="text" placeholder="http://www." />
            <label for="domainToBeReged0">Domain:</label><input name="domainToBeReged0" type="text" placeholder="http://www." />
</div>
```

.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('hostingRequired','HostingRequired','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('domainRequired','DomainRequired','required');
```